# winform not creating file in read-only folders

Tags: c#, file-writing

I am trying to create a file in a directory using the code below

```
if (File.Exists(myDir))
{
    return myDir;
}
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(myDir);
File.SetAttributes(myDir, FileAttributes.Normal);

//string name = myDir + "/" + filename;
File.Create(myDir).Dispose();
return myDir;
```

When I run it on a Mac it works since the directory have write permission, however, I have noticed that on windows 10 all folders are automatically read only, so the access to write in the path is denied.

What would be the solution for me to write a file in this path?

Btw if I use this path which is my MacBook directory (read&write permission) :  "//Mac/Home/Movies" it will just work as it should, it will create the subdirectories and the file in it, however if I choose the windows one which is "C:\CSVtest" it would just show "access denied as it is read-only, i can't find a way to bypass this read-only thing, i tried on other windows 10 machines as well and all folders on windows 10 are read-only so it is the same case

Comment: "all folders are automatically read only", no they aren't. What is `myDir`?

Comment: out of interest... C# on a Mac with WinForms? are you running Mono or Xamarin.Mac setup? or Maybe the Core.Net for Mac ?

Comment: It seems you are trying to create a directory _and_ a file with the same name, you use `myDir` in both calls. That is not allowed on Windows.

Comment: myDir is the string variable that contains the directory path, I run windows on a mac using parallel, on my windows 10 all the folders on here are read-only but if I run the same code but with a directory of my mac, it would create it without any problem, I have the impression that even if I manually set it to read&write windows will automatically put it in on read-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//path = @"C:\Temp\Bar\Foo\Test.txt";
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
```

Directory.CreateDirectory will create the directories recursively and if the directory already exist it will return without an error.

You then would create the file

```
File.Create(path).Dispose();
```

Comment: I see but how come if i choose a directory on my mac's root which has read&write permission it all works perfectly

Comment: Are you left with *both* a file and a directory on your mac or does creating the file remove the directory?

Comment: it creates the directory with all the subfolders and the file in the last folder, so it would just as it should, only when i choose for examplepath = "C:\Temp\ then it will say access denied, btw i didn't use the "@" is it important?

Comment: i find out, just like @Renevogt mentioned I had mixed up the create directory and create file together, i got confused about the read-only thing as it was working on my mac, what a coincidence but thanks a lot